# Chromecast ios: stream html content

Tags: ios, xamarin, chromecast

I started developing my own app for streaming a html website to the chromecast.
In the documentation it says that google installed a default app for displaying content like HTML, Videos, Images etc.
I tried it and videos and images are working well (url ending = ".mp3" or ".mkv"). But when I am trying to stream a website (url ending = ".html) it simply doesnt stream anything.

I am doing this with a mediachannel and mediaInfo.

```
var mediaInfo = new GCKMediaInformation (url, GCKMediaStreamType.None, "unkown", metadata, 0, null);
```

Thanks in advance
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where did you see in our documentation that "html" was supported as a type of content for our Default Receiver? Our [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/receiver_apps#default) for the Default Receiver states: "A third option available is the Default Media Receiver. This is a pre-built receiver application hosted by Google that is designed for streaming your audio and video content."

In short, the Default Receiver only supports media contents of the specified types, not an html content.

Comment: Sorry. I just double checked it. I read the reciever part and saw HTML 5 there. My fault.

Comment: Is there a possibility to stream html content to the chromecast without creating an own reciever?

Comment: No, you need to create your own receiver.